# Cannot read property of undefined React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state

So I have data coming in from an API, to be rendered in a tab component... a function that accepts data from the api and renders it in the component

issue is, the data isnt persistent, despite me storing it in Localstorage,
because of this, when I call the generateTabs method and put parameters like in the code below, it throws errors  - Cannot read property 'topic' of undefined

is there a way to make it conditionally render based on the data?
or await the data before reading the parameters?
maybe make it asynchronous?

Summary of issue:

data comes from API -- access with function(parameters passed as props to component) -- store in localStorage -- setState from localStorage -- refresh page --  Cannot read property 'topic' of undefined

I want it to await the data before rendering in the tabs... so persisting isnt an ideal solution

```
    useEffect(()=> {
        localStorage.setItem('news', JSON.stringify(news))
    },[])

    useEffect(()=> {
        const data = localStorage.getItem('news')
        const mainData = JSON.parse(data)
        setArticle(mainData)
        console.log(article)
        
    },[])
    
const generateTabs =  (topic, article)=> {
    
     
    return  <Tab tabType = 'tab' className ='nws-container-mid' topic = {topic} article = {article}  />
           
}

     
   

    return (
        <div className ="wrapper">
        
     
        <div className="container__Dash">
                <Header name = {name}/>


                <div className ="container__new">
                    
                    <div className ="container__tab surface"> 
                        <FeaturedNews  userOptions = {userOptions} country = {country} />
                        <PictureOfTheDay userOptions = {userOptions} />
                    </div>
                    <div className ="container__tab middle"> 
                        {/* {console.log(article[0].topic)} */}

                       {generateTabs((article[0].topic))}
                       {generateTabs()}
                       {generateTabs()}
                       <button onClick={openModal}>Set Modal </button>
                       <Modal showModal={showModal} setModal = {setModal} > </Modal>
                        
 
                    </div> 
                   
                       <div className ="container__tab footer">

                       {generateTabs()}
                       {generateTabs()}

                        <Settings />
                        <Weather location = {location} country = {country}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default DashBoard
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect() is executed after the rendering. so for your first render, it renders the wrapper div and tries to read the article[0].topic)), but the article state has not been set yet, that is why the error happens.

to prevent the error, use

```
 {article.length!==0 && generateTabs(article[0].topic,article[0].article)}
```

the generateTabs function will be called only when the article array is not empty.

In addition, `{generateTabs()}` does not pass value to it, so the article and topic will be null for the Tab component.

```
  return  <Tab tabType = 'tab' className ='nws-container-mid' topic = {topic} article = {article}  />
```